# Using multiple Cultures in an application

Tags: c#, culture

I'm having trouble in my app managing one Culture used for data and one used for user-interaction.  For data I want the Culture to always be English, as that's how I'm specifying my dates, prices, etc and how I need them to be parsed.  However when displaying strings to the user those should be shown formatted correctly for the user's Culture.

Currently I'm not specifying a Culture so typically everything is processed using the user's Culture by default.  I then fix the problems as they arise on an ad-hoc basis, but this is not ideal.  I need a more systemic approach.  Is there a way to specify the culture that should always be used on a class by class basis?  Or some other way to manage cultures better than what I'm currently doing?

Comment: What's on the backend?

Comment: We're just using Node JS on the backend, but the part I'm concerned about are the frontend systems in C#.